# Calling A prototype from itself on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to call iteration from itself, what would be the best way to do it?

```
function Items(names) {
    this.name = "Bo";
    this.iteration();
}

Items.prototype.iteration = function(){
    console.log("calling iteration");
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.iteration(); // <----------- Wrong 
        this.prototype.iteration(); // <----------- Wrong 
        // right way <-------------- undefined
    } ,1000 );
}
```

Thought these would work just like `this.name` would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind your function to the current context (=> `this`), for example with the `bind` function:

```
function Items(names) {
    this.name = "Bo";
    this.iteration();
}

Items.prototype.iteration = function(){
    console.log("calling iteration");
    setTimeout(this.iteration.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to you use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind callback function to correct context:

```
Items.prototype.iteration = function() {
    console.log("calling iteration");
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.iteration();
        this.prototype.iteration();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Preserve the object in a variable, then call `iteration`

```js
function Items(names) {
  this.iteration();
}

Items.prototype.iteration = function() {
  var self = this;
  console.log("calling iteration");
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.iteration();
  }, 1000);
}

var item = new Items();
```

Comment: What is more right/common to use? Defining self or using bind? Your opinion?

Comment: @user3800799, Ive seen both and I don't have enough knowledge to give you the pros/cons of both approaches